# Proving Independence due to exchangeability?

Tags: independence, conditional-independence, exchangeability

I have a set of bernoulli random variables $\{x_i\}^{n}_{i=1}$ and $\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j}$. They have a probability distribution with following conditional independence:

$$P(\{x_i\}^{n}_{i=1},\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j}) = p(x_1,...,x_n)\prod_{i<j}P(x_{ij}|x_i,x_j)$$

Now, I know the following additional conditions about this distribution:

**Exchangeability:**
For any permutation $\sigma$, the following holds:

$$P\left(\{x_i\}^{n}_{i=1},\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j}\right) =P\left(\{x_{\sigma(i)}\}^{n}_{i=1},\{x_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}\}_{i< j}\right) $$

**Projectivity:** The distribution is defined by some generative model such that for any $n \geq m$ the probability distribution $P(\{x_i\}^{m}_{i=1},\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j})$ can be uniquely obtained by marginalising out all additional variables from $P(\{x_i\}^{n}_{i=1},\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j})$.

Can I always say that the distribution is given as:

$$P(\{x_i\}^{n}_{i=1},\{x_{ij}\}_{i< j}) = \prod_{i}P(x_i)\prod_{i<j}P(x_{ij}|x_i,x_j)$$

Simply put, does exchangeability and projectivity for the given form of distribution implies independence of $x_i$'s ?

Comment: If I've understood **projectivity** correctly, I think the distribution given by $z_0\sim Bernoulli(0.5)$, $x_i=x_{ij}=z_0$ satisfies your conditions and isn't independent.

Comment: @ThomasLumley thanks alot, that solves it !